# How to extract json attribute in Xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to extract json data in the html attribute. This is my xpah: I got null so far. The link is https://wefunder.com/beta.bionics

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="sb-site"]/div/div[4]/*[name()="wf:loader"]/@company-json').extract()
```

Here is the screenshot of the webpage:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do not post links to images.  Post XML in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to specify the tag name here at all - just get an *element having the `company-json` attribute*. Demo using Scrapy (I recognized the syntax):

```
$ scrapy shell https://wefunder.com/beta.bionics
>>> response.xpath("//*[@company-json]/@company-json").extract_first()
u'{"company":{"id":9512,"url":"beta...
...rait_photo_url":false}}'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! A little more doubt, why doesn't adding the prefix work for this case?

Comment: @BowenLiu you should've handled the namespaces if you wanted to check the tag name in this case. Or, you could've used the `local-name()` instead of `name()`. I've just chosen the practical approach :) Glad to be helpful.